# resque-meta and multiple arguments in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, resque, resque-meta

I recently switched to using [Resque-meta](https://github.com/lmarlow/resque-meta) and now I'm a bit confused with how best to handle multiple arguments.  I was passing it as the first ID, but using the meta plugin, the meta id becomes the ID, and it breaks.

```
c=MessifyAsync.enqueue(5094, Date.today)
```

Now it shows the first ID as meta stamp

```
["0cb5843267d5eaef77eaf770ece86bb2850f46bc", 5094, "2011-07-29"]
```

Code:

```
require 'resque/plugins/resque_heroku_autoscaler'
require 'resque-meta'

class MessifyAsync
  extend Resque::Plugins::HerokuAutoscaler
  extend Resque::Plugins::Meta

  @queue = :messify

  def self.perform(space_id, date = Date.today+7.days)
    Available.messify(:id => space_id, :date => date)
  end

end
```